# I configured IIS7 for PHP, but it won't handle any non *.php files

Tags: php, windows, iis, iis-7

I have Windows Vista Home Premium (and thus IIS 7) and am trying to run a local web server so I can work on a PHP project of mine without an internet connection. I followed PHP's guides [for Windows manual installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php) and [for IIS7](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php) to a tee. The server is now working such that I can access PHP files on the server, but all other files return a blank page. I imagine I need to setup a handler mapping in IIS 7 for all other filetypes or something, but I don't know how to do that. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Psst: Apache is available for *all* windows versions (yes even for crappy Window Me or Vista). It's a great webserver and it works very well with PHP. The best thing is: If you change your operating system, you don't need to change much.